# app js getting merge conflict when merging branch with master (laravel+vue)

Tags: laravel, git, vue.js, deployment, node-modules

I am developing an application using `Laravel` and `vueJs`. During build up the application, the `npm run watch` command watching all relevant files for changes and recompiling `app.js` when it detects a change. First time, I created a repository (suppose in github/gitlab/bitbucket etc.) with a master branch and two different branches.

Now, the problem is when we're going to push to the branch or merge with master branch, it's getting so many conflicts in `public/js/app.js`. I guess, I know the reason. This is because of, during build the application with `npm run watch`, every changes recompiling the `app.js`. So, old `public/js/app.js` in the repository will get the `merge conflict` in new `public/js/app.js`. If I ignore the `app.js` then how the changes impact to the app when multiple developers work at the same time. In this circumstances, what should be the solution when the application is developing by two or more developers and using github,gitlab,gitbucket etc. to merge the codes. Would someone suggest me the correct way please!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ignore compiled files in your `.gitignore` as there's no reason to push them to your repository unless you don't have `nodejs` in your server

`.gitignore`:

```
/public/js/app.js
```

Then run

```
npm install
npm run prod
```

In your server when you're ready to deploy

#### Steps to correct

```
rm public/js/app.js
echo "/public/js/app.js" >> .gitignore
git commit -m "ignore compiled asset"
git push
npm run watch
```

I usually ignore all compiled assets in public directory

```
/public/js/*
/public/css/*
/public/fonts
```

Because it's cleaner and faster to push (since the compiled assets are huge in size +1MB)

It's better to have all dependencies in `node_modules` and write Javascript as ES6 modules in `resources/js` or formerly `resources/assets/js` (same thing for CSS & SCSS)

Comment: We are two, working in the same project, when we are working at the same time then, if `app.js` recompiled then our two `app.js` is different for recompiling reason, is not it? If, yes, then how to merge these two.

Comment: Don't merge it! delete the file locally and ignore it in `.gitignore`, commit and push and tell the other developer to pull, you'll always keep getting merge conflict because it's not meant to be pushed in git

Comment: I am getting confused. When recompiled, is not changes the code inside `app.js`?

Comment: Yes but these changes are generated by webpack, the other developer won't read these changes on their own, it's the changes in `resources/js/app.js` that matters

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put the compiled files in git, remove the app.js in your public directory from your git repository. Your friend just has to run npm run prod on his machine to get an updated app.js.